# unable to load asset as i provide full path

Tags: flutter, widget

i have kept images inside assets/images in the root directory of project ,
added assets to the pubsepcs.yaml file as

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

and in the main.dart file i had added image widget as :

```
Image.asset("assets/images/1.png", height: 250,width: 250)
```

still cant load assets in the application

i had also performed flutter clean
tried to rerun the app and rebuild also ,
as there seems no indentaion errors also

Comment: Try to flutter clean, then rebuild.

Comment: where is assets folder located?

Answer (score 1):

Only files located directly in the directory are included unless there are files with the same name inside a subdirectory (see Asset Variants). To add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory.

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images